# How to show all available routes in Spring?

Tags: spring, routes

How to show all the routes mapped in a spring based application? In Rails this is done using rake routes.

I use two mapping methods of spring to create the URL-mappings:

- `@RequestMapping`
- `SimpleUrlHandler`

I have used the Unix command `grep` and `cut` to get all the mappings of `@RequestMapping`. I wonder if there is some way I can get these details from the Spring application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you set the Log4J category for `log4j.logger.org.springframework.web` to `INFO` or `DEBUG` you should see the list of mappings in your server's log (e.g. `catalina.out`) when your app starts up.

For example:

```
INFO: DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/about] onto handler [org.bozos.songfight.webapp.spring.controller.RootController@6bc947]
INFO: DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/about.*] onto handler [org.bozos.songfight.webapp.spring.controller.RootController@6bc947]
INFO: DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/about/] onto handler [org.bozos.songfight.webapp.spring.controller.RootController@6bc947]
...
INFO: SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController@4035acf6]
```

Comment: in my case the above property didnot work, I had to set `logging.level.org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG`

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is how to do it when using Spring boot. My answer is specifically for when using Spring Framework without Spring Boot, and for configuring Log4J directly rather than via Spring Boot.

Comment: Spring Boot 3: TRACE helped :)

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Intellij (ultimate edition), then after you build/run the project, you can view the routes in the bottom toolbar `Run` -> `Endpoints` -> `Mappings`.

[image]

Comment: it is worth noting that if you can't see the mappings tab when running your spring boot app then you probably want to do the following: 1- Enable MVC Spring plugin (if it is not already enabled), 2- Add actuator to your dependencies

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator maven dependency for the actuator

Comment: Is there any way to print out the routes with the command line?

Comment: @robskrob i had the same question. did u find an answer ? maybe a gradle task?

Comment: @Sandeep I did not find an answer to this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

### Solution

This can be done with spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.5 which makes use of spring-webmvc:5.3.17.
Add this config to your application.yml (or similar):

```
logging:
  level:
    _org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.Mappings: debug
```

The underscore '_' in the logger name is important.
This property will generate logs during application boot that look like this
[image: example of logs from spring-webmvc:5.3.17's AbstractHandlerMapping.class]

### How it works

The property references spring-webmvc:5.3.17's org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.**AbstractHandlerMapping** which creates a hidden logger for mappings
[image: spring-webmvc:5.3.17's AbstractHandlerMapping.class logger declaration]

This logger gets used in method *detectHandlerMethods*() of subclass **AbstractHandlerMethodMapping**
[image: spring-webmvc:5.3.17's AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.class]

It looks like this technique goes back as early as spring-webmvc 5.3.5 (march 2021):
[Github Spring Framework Release 5.3.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v5.3.5)

Here's the commit containing the changes:
[Github Spring Framework commit with changes for logging routes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/3ec0452fed9675cac4676f05c8ca461f0d96dd30)

Comment: Thanks, very useful tip and really easy to activate temporarily for quick insights! I never heard of "hidden" spring loggers before.