# How to show all available routes in Spring Boot with the Command Line?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

How can I print all my routes out in a Spring Boot application with the command line? I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686196/how-to-show-all-available-routes-in-spring) has been asked before, but the answers either assume one is using Intellij or wants to see the printed routes in the local server logs.

For some background information, I use vim and build my application locally with the command line Gradle commands. I am not using an IDE such as Intellij.

Comment: what about the accepted answer on the linked question?

Comment: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-get-all-endpoints) may be helpful for you

Comment: @Janar the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686304/10871900) is not about IntelliJ.

Comment: Ok yeah the accepted answer is about logging out the routes in the server logs when the app starts up. I could look into that -- but what I would like is some command-line command that prints out the routes in my terminal shell.